# HBase archive files are kept for too long

Tags: hbase

We are running HBase with replication on for a while now. Recently, the archive files kept growing in the .archive directory. We ended up having 3 to 4 times our actual data in the .archive directory. Debug logs on Hbase master doesn't show anything relevant. As far I know, the replication should only effect the WALs and should have no effect on the .archive directory (the hFiles). We have a backup master running as well. I'm not sure if a misconfiguration there can have a bad effect. I can see in the logs that the "TimeToLiveHFileCleaner" is being initialized. From the source code, the default value for the time to live is (hbase.master.hfilecleaner.ttl) 5 minutes. But this is not happening (I'm not seeing anything in the logs and the files stay).

Thanks in advance for any solutions/suggestions.

Comment: did you figure out what was causing it? We are facing the same problem

Comment: I forgot to update this but we had a background service that takes snapshots and exports it to another cluster. I did not notice that when I posted this question. It was infact our snapshots which were keeping the HFileCleaner from deleting the files.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when either

- HMaster cleaner chore is not running => manually failover to an other
  HMaster to start it up again, because if it fails somehow, it's not
  restarted on that same HMaster.
- Snapshots are keeping the files there => review snapshots created about the relevant table(s) that has the high usage. Removing old snapshots will free up their respective data files under archive.
- Review if the table has KEEP_DELETED_CELLS as that would also keep
  files under archive
- Check if TTL is in line with your data retention needs. Same goes for VERSION number. => review if data would be rolled out fast, but MajorCompaction would not be running too often as it's only when running MC is when data deletion actually happens.